# Next.js event type error in arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, event-handling, arrow-functions

I've created my `handleChange()` function with some event to handle event from my input. The problem is that I don't know what to add to solve the error.

Here below screenshot of this:

[image]

I'm using Next.js. In React I would never see something like that.

Thank you in advance for help.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've set up your Next.js project with TypeScript and your typescript configuration has [noImplicitAny](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) check enabled, that causes that error to be reported.

**Easiest** way to fix it would be to explicitly set **event** type to **any**.

```
const handleChange = (event: any) => {
```

**Much better way** to fix it would be to use a proper TypeScript type **React.ChangeEvent**

```
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
```